# How do I user Jenkins warnings-ng-plugin - SonarQube Analysis?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

I just installed ["Jenkins Warnings Next Generation Plugin"](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Next+Generation+Plugin) and was wondering how to use the "SonarQube"    Static Analysis Tools there.

I found out, that it will parse the result of "sonar-report.json" but I don't know how this files is being generated.

Looking in the SonarQube Documentation I only found out, that the "sonar-report.json" was generated using the "preview mode" which is deprecated since SonarQube 6.6

Does anyone have an Idea how to generate this file with then newest SonarQube (7.4+) or is the Warnings Plugin for SonarQube useless?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [SonarSource Community](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonar-report-json-is-this-file-still-available/5827/3) it is possible to generate the sonar-report.json using

```
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.report.export.path=sonar-report.json
```

Nevertheless this parameter is marked as deprecated and should not be used anymore

```
WARN: The use of the issues mode (sonar.analysis.mode=issues) is deprecated. This mode will be dropped in the future.
```

Comment: The future has come and this option is no longer available, any ideas how to make it work on current or most up to date versions?
"ERROR: The preview mode, along with the 'sonar.analysis.mode' parameter, is no more supported. You should stop using this parameter."